# How to use pytest fixtures in mock decorators?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I want to use a pytest fixture in mock.patch decorator but I get an error says it is undefined. Is it possible to use fixtures in decorators?

I've a simple fixture in conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture
def file_loader():
    """Loads data from given path"""

    def _loader(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data

    return _loader
```

I want this fixture's return value to be my mock return_value but I get file_loader is not defined error.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("service.my_func", mock.MagicMock(return_value=file_loader("file_path"))
def test_my_func():
    ...
```

Comment: That is not possible. Fixtures cannot be used as functions, only as arguments in tests and other fixtures.